# Index out of date on appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm doing this query on my live appengine site:

```
orders = models.Order.gql("WHERE status IN ('accepted','packing') ORDER BY created_on DESC").fetch(100)
```

To my surprise, I get results where the status is not in 'accepted' or 'packing', but 'cancelled'.  I've never seen this problem before and I just noticed it today:

```
for order in orders:
...     order.status
... 
u'accepted'
u'accepted'
u'cancelled'
u'cancelled'
u'accepted'
```

Any thoughts? It seems like something is fundamentally wrong.  I'm not caching any results, this was all on the remote shell and it happens on my live site.

Comment: Could you try w/o the `ORDER BY` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your entities have recently changed, this could be Datastore's *eventual consistency* in action.  When you update your entities, it takes a while for the indexes to reflect your changes, while the entities themselves are up-to-date.

If you data is [structured appropriately](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency), you could try an ancestor query and see what happens.

Comment: Yup, this must've been it -- because the same query no longer returns the non-matching results!  It was inconsistent for atleast 20 minutes as I thought about it and wrote up the original post, if not longer.